# How is the equation for the position of a virtual site derived?

Tags: molecular-dynamics, mathematical-modeling, gromacs, derivations

[Cross posted on Math SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4780773/how-is-the-equation-for-this-virtual-site-derived)

I am trying to understand virtual sites in MD simulations, and I came across this configuration:

[image: Virtual sites diagram]

Here, coordinate $\mathbf{s}$ represents the virtual site, which is formed by three other atoms $\mathbf{i}$, $\mathbf{j}$, and $\mathbf{k}$. The distance between atom $\mathbf{i}$ and the virtual site $\mathbf{s}$ is $|\mathbf{d}|$. The position of atoms $\mathbf{i}$, $\mathbf{j}$, and $\mathbf{k}$ are $\mathbf{r}_i$, $\mathbf{r}_j$, and $\mathbf{r}_k$, respectively.

In this case, the virtual site ($\mathbf{r}_s$) is in the plane of the other three particles at a distance of $|\mathbf{d}|$ from $\mathbf{i}$ at an angle of $\theta$ from $\mathbf{r}_{ij}$. Atom $\mathbf{k}$ defines the plane and direction of the angle.

How should I get the position of $\mathbf{r}_s$ using the other three atom positions and an angle?

I know the equation for $\mathbf{r}_s$, but I couldn't understand how it is derived. Any help is appreciated.
$$
\mathbf{r}_s = \mathbf{r}_i 
+ d \cos\theta\, \frac{\mathbf{r}_{ij}}{|\mathbf{r}_{ij}|}
+ d \sin\theta\, \frac{\mathbf{r}_{\perp}}{|\mathbf{r}_{\perp}|}\tag{1}, 
$$
in which
$$
\mathbf{r}_{\perp} = \mathbf{r}_{jk} 
- \frac{\mathbf{r}_{ij} \cdot \mathbf{r}_{jk}}{\mathbf{r}_{ij} \cdot \mathbf{r}_{ij}}\, \mathbf{r}_{ij}. \tag{2}
$$

Comment: I think it's already mentioned in gromacs manual and the subsequent paper.

Comment: @RoshanShrestha why not show where in the manual and where in the paper it's answered? Some people might not even know which paper to seek!

Comment: Wouldn't it just be $\mathbf{r_i} + \frac{d \left(\mathbf{r_j}- \mathbf{r_k}\right)}{|\mathbf{r_j}- \mathbf{r_k}|}$? If you already have $\mathbf{r_i}$, then why would an angle $\theta$ that has nothing to do with the length $d$ matter?

Comment: My bad, thanks @NikeDattani So, in the book Molecular Liquids
Dynamics and Interactions, there is a chapter written by H.J.C. Berendsen and W.F. van Gunsteren from Page 475-500 on Molecular dynamics simulations: techniques and approaches.

Comment: @RoshanShrestha, Yes, you are correct. I went through that book thoroughly. I did manage to derive for simple cases (as given in the book), but for this configuration, I couldn't.

Comment: @NikeDattani updated the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The formula (1) in the question:

$$
\mathbf{r}_s = \underset{\text{term A}}{\mathbf{r}_i}
+ \underset{\text{term B}}{d \cos\theta\, \frac{\mathbf{r}_{ij}}{|\mathbf{r}_{ij}|}}
+ \underset{\text{term C}}{d \sin\theta\, \frac{\mathbf{r}_{\perp}}{|\mathbf{r}_{\perp}|}}\tag{1}
$$

can be understood as going to the position of $s$ by starting at the position of $i$ (term A) and adding the two legs (terms B and C) of the right-angled triangle with $\mathbf{r}_{is}$ as its hypotenuse (equivalently, stating $\mathbf{r}_{is}$ in the orthonormal basis vectors of terms B and C).

Term B is the unit vector $\hat{\mathbf{r}}_{ij}$, and term C is the unit vector coplanar and perpendicular to $\hat{\mathbf{r}}_{ij}$. The (not yet unit) vector $\mathbf{r}_\perp$ in term C is constructed to lie in the desired plane but be perpendicular to $\mathbf{r}_{ij}$ by subtracting from $\mathbf{r}_{jk}$ its projection into $\mathbf{r}_{ij}$ (a [Gram-Schmidt orthogonalization](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram%E2%80%93Schmidt_process)). This is the formula (2) in the question.

The below diagram may help visually:

[image: Geometry of atoms k, j, i, and virtual site s, showing the vector is as the sum of basis vectors parallel and perpendicular to in.]

Comment: Useful relations to help understand this answer: $\sin(\theta - \pi)=-\sin(\theta),\cos(\theta-\pi)=-\cos(\theta).$

Answer (score 2):

I have posted the [same question in Mathematics StackExchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4780773/how-is-the-equation-for-this-virtual-site-derived) and here is the reply.

> Suppose that $d=|\mathbf{d}|$ and $\mathbf{r}_{ij}\ne \mathbf{0}$. Then in the plane of the other three particles with the coordinates origin at $\mathbf{r}_i$ and the basis of consisting of the unit vector $\frac{\mathbf{r}_{ij}}{|\mathbf{r}_{ij}|}$ and some orthogonal to it unit vector $\mathbf{r'}$, the virtual site has coordinates $(d\cos\theta,d\sin\theta)$. Thus
> $$\mathbf{r}_s = \mathbf{r}_i
> + d \cos\theta\, \frac{\mathbf{r}_{ij}}{|\mathbf{r}_{ij}|}
> + d \sin\theta\, \mathbf{r'}.$$
> The vector $\mathbf{r'}$ belongs to the plane spanned by $\mathbf{r}_{ij}$ and $\mathbf{r}_{jk}$, so
> $\mathbf{r'}=\lambda_i\mathbf{r}_{ij}+\lambda_k\mathbf{r}_{jk}$ for some real $\lambda_i$ and $\lambda_k$. Moreover,
> $0=\mathbf{r'}\cdot \mathbf{r}_{ij}=\lambda_i\mathbf{r}_{ij}\cdot \mathbf{r}_{ij}+\lambda_k\mathbf{r}_{jk}\cdot \mathbf{r}_{ij}$.
> So $\lambda_i=-\lambda_k\frac{\mathbf{r}_{jk}\cdot \mathbf{r}_{ij}}{\mathbf{r}_{ij}\cdot \mathbf{r}_{ij}}$.
> Thus
> $$\mathbf{r'}=\lambda_k\left(-\frac{\mathbf{r}_{jk}\cdot \mathbf{r}_{ij}}{\mathbf{r}_{ij}\cdot \mathbf{r}_{ij}}\mathbf{r}_{ij}
> +\mathbf{r}_{jk}\right)=-\lambda_k\mathbf{r}_{\perp}.$$
> Since $|\mathbf{r'}|=1$, we have $|\lambda_k|=\frac{1}{|\mathbf{r}_{\perp}|}$. It remains to determine the sign of $\lambda_k$.
> It corresponds to the direction of the angle $\theta$ between $\mathbf{r}_{ij}$ and $\mathbf{r}_{s}-\mathbf{r}_{i}$.
> In particular, when $\theta=\frac{\pi}{2}$, we have $\mathbf{r'}=\mathbf{r}_s-\mathbf{r}_i$. But this direction is not very clear to me, maybe, because there is no coordinate system in the supplementary picture.